# Having trouble setting up gtuner computer vision

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Can anybody help me set up Gtuner computer vision I done downloaded everything but it's all still confusing and I keep getting this

> GCV Error: No module named 'cv2' Traceback (most recent call last): File “”, line 1, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘cv2’
>
> Computer Vision: ERROR: Gpython process exited with error code 111

I've uninstalled and re-installed and still nothing. I have been at this for two days - if anyone can walk me through it that would be helpful. Again, it's gtuner cv and I don't have a capture card so I'm using remote play

Pip list
Numpy 1.26.4
Opencv-python 4.9.0.80
Pip 24.0
Pywin 306
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ZVY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xytrK.jpg)

Comment: Full output of `pip list` please. Not in a comment. [edit] your question to add the output.

Comment: Like that ? Also I added to picture to clarify a lil more

Comment: oh no, you installed multiple opencv packages in the same python! I've given you an answer for that issue. I can't be sure that's the issue you're facing but it is *an* issue you need to rectify because the packages interfere with each other in most cases. -- since you're new, please take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All OpenCV-Python package variants contain the base modules. Some lack GUI modules. Some additionally bring contrib modules.

- `opencv-python` - base
- `opencv-contrib-python` - base and contrib
- `opencv-python-headless` - base, no GUI
- `opencv-contrib-python-headless` - base and contrib, no GUI

The package variants are mutually exclusive. When you install multiple of them, they usually interfere with each other and break the installation.

You have installed both `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`. Uninstall both. Then install one of them.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python opencv-contrib-python opencv-python-headless opencv-contrib-python-headless
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: I just uninstalled them all and reinstalled opencv-python so now that should be the only one I was also informed I may have multiple pythons installed and I do I have one in C:\Program Files\Python312 and C:\Users\name\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python

Comment: do you mean to say that it works now? if it doesn't, let me know -- multiple pythons can get confusing. if the PATH environment variable is set up inconsistently, you might get the `pip` of one but the `python` of the other installation. you can work around that by invoking pip as `python -m pip ...` -- when in doubt, create a `venv` or `virtualenv`, then install your required packages into that environment.

Comment: Naah its still a ❌ there and do you think I should just delete the entire folder that’s in the program files since when I installed python it’s in appdata\local etc and not there

Comment: I'd recommend uninstalling python through Windows "add or remove programs", if it's listed there.